# Как на Aiogram можно сделать систему антифлуда?

Tags: python, aiogram

Как на Aiogram можно сделать систему антифлуда в чате? Вот примерно такую систему

1. Бот смотрит все чаты
2. Если кто то ввел в каком то из чате больше 2-х сообщений (одинаковых) то выдает бан навечно этому пользователю

Версия Aiogram-2.21

Comment: "Привет" в одном чате и "Привет" в другом = бан на вечно? )))

Comment: нет. Мне нужно если именно в каком то чате какой то человек ввел к примеру 2 или больше раз сообщей к примеру "привет" в 3 секунды то его банят )))

Comment: Забудте язык программирования. Возьмите бумажку и напишите как бы вы это делали вручную. Затем вспомните язык программирования и переложите алгоритм на код. Списки вам в помощь. / сообщение -> в список, проверка, что в списке нет х одинаковых сообщений. Раз в n секунд удаляйте первый элемент списка. Если в списке х одинаковых - бан. Ну как то так

Comment: алгоритм я и так написал.